# Issue with Communication between Chrome Extension UI page and content script

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension

Noob question here:

Last week I wrote a very basic Chrome Extension, in which a popup.js sends a message to a content.js script, in the following way (maybe it was not the BEST way, but the important thing here is that it worked. Why it is important? Bear with me...)

In popup.js

```
someButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'src/content.js',
    }, () => {
        connect();
    });
});
```

and later:

```
function connect() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id);
        port.postMessage({ type: 'info', data: someValue });
    })
}
```

In the content.js

```
if (!chrome.runtime.onConnect.hasListeners()) {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
        port.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
            if (msg && msg.type == "info") {
               // do some stuff
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This worked, but I believe is not the best way. I've been reading much more since last week, and know I believe the right way should be something like this:

On popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true },  (tabs) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
        type: "info",
        someValue: value
      });
    });
```

And in content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.type == "info"){
           sendResponse({ message: "some answer" }) 
        }
        return true;
    })
```

But in my new version, this does not work, even if every tutorial and the documentation says it should. I do not receive any error, simple the function added to the listener it is never executed.

I suspect that maybe it could be related that now I am using React and Webpack, and maybe Webpack is doing something weird?

A fragment of my manifest.json

```
 "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.bundle.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.bundle.js"]
    }],
```

Maybe the problem is that I am specifying the content and background with the bundles? Not sure, the only thing I know is that according to what I understand, this should be working and it is not.

What am I missing?

PS: I should add that I been debugging and I found the content files are being executed, and the piece of code that sends the message also has been executed. It is like the addListener is not added properly, or for some reason never received the message.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `content_scripts` in manifest.json it runs between `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events by default so if you opened the popup on a complex page that's still loading, there'll be no content script to receive a message.

You can specify ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) to make the content script run at "start" when the page is still empty, the DOM will only have `document.documentElement` for the `<html>` node, there'll be no `<head>` or `<body>`.

Note that a content script declared in manifest.json always runs in every matching page so **if your extension needs the content script only after a click in the popup**, this will be very very bad because you're wasting the resources 99.999% of time and effectively require broad host permissions. In that case you should 1) remove `content_scripts` from manifest.json, 2) add `activeTab` in "permissions" and remove any broad host permissions such as `<all_urls>` or `*://*/*` or `http://*/*`, 3) use executeScript and hasListeners as you did before.

Comment: thanks you very much, as always, your answer is very clarifying. But sadly, I still have some doubts. For example, as I used the executeScript, I sent the file name, but with webpack, should have to use the bundle name? Something like `chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      null,
      {
        file: "content.bundle.js",
      },
      () => {
        connect();
      }
    );`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of the code, comments have less flexibility for that

Comment: Can't help with webpack. It depends on your webpack config so try asking a new question about that.